# Send data to a server from a web mobile app

Tags: php, cordova, post, mobile, send

My question is, how can I send a data (for example a text box) from a web mobile app (cordova) to my own server and save that data in server?

I tried post method but I couldn't run it completely.

Comment: Please see **how to ask a good question** https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Post some code maybe? What is going wrong? Any error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX request to make post requests to the PHP server.

You can find a documentation [Ajax request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)  using pure Javascript here.

Or using Jquery [Ajax API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Watch out for [CROS](https://enable-cors.org/server_php.html) and Acces Control if you are not in localhost.